# What is the purpose of the hashcode used in Exchange OWA HTTP requests?

Tags: hash, exchange

This [blog describes the URLs that are used in OWA and webservices](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/exchangedev/budget-snapshots-in-the-iis-logs).  It also says that there is a hashcode that is used in conjunction with the throttling policy.

- Is this hashcode responsible for "securing" the throttling policy, and its current values for later processing by a CAS server?
- What format is this hashcode?  (is it MD5, SHA1, etc?)

Comment: Assuming they didn't truncate the hash value in the example they showed, it looks way too small to be a crypto hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My (wild) guess is that the "hashcode" is just a reference key used by whatever system enforces the throttling, to quickly locate in an internal database (which could be an in-RAM [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)) the entry which keeps track of the "budget" allocated to each entity. Thus not a *cryptographic* hash at all.